# No funciona mi aplicacion en Angular 13 luego de ejecutar ng build

Tags: angular, xampp, localhost

tengo un pequeño proyecto desarrollado en Angular 13 que quiero desplegar en un servidor XAMPP, ya genere el empaquetado dentro de la carpeta dist usando el comando ng build --prod. Mas sin embargo luego de colocar esa carpeta en el servidor, no se visualiza la pagina.
En consola me muestra el siguiente error, pero dentro del archivo index si esta especificado la ruta de esos archivos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se encuentra asi

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ReciprocalTransactions</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://bootswatch.com/5/lux/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.ef46db3751d8e999.css">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="./runtime.28362c205640769c.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="./polyfills.5a6684c600b77e0f.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="./main.5205cf6d5594e68b.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás trabajando con XAMPP en subdirectorio, debes crear el build para dicho subdirectorio.

Si tu aplicación se encuentra en localhost:8080/angular/

```
ng build --prod --base-href /angular/
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.